# Why django group by wrong field? annotate()

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, model, rdbms

Why Django Group by id Field?
Here is queryset:

```
MyModel.objects\
    .filter(
        status=1,
        created__gte=datestart,
        created__lte=dateend)\
    .values('terminal_id')\
    .annotate(
        total_pa=Sum('amount'),
        total_ar=Sum('amount_result')).query
```

But it order and group by pk field.

... GROUP BY `payment`.`id` ORDER BY `payment`.`id` ...

Instead of

... GROUP BY `payment`.`terminal_id` ORDER BY `payment`.`terminal_id` ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See the "Warning" here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/aggregation/#interaction-with-default-ordering-or-order-by

Perhaps the default ordering is getting in the way. Try adding `.order_by()` to the end of your query to see if that clears the ordering.

Comment: You are my saviour!:)

Comment: we didn't understand :(